# Posting message to Facebook wall in Flex mobile project

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, mobile

I am very new to flex and AS3. I want develop a mobile app that should be able to post message on wall of the user in Facebook. I got examples for desktop app, but I am not getting any examples for mobile app.

I don't how to start for mobile app. Please help me through some tutorials or examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greate mobile tutorial
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/testdrivemobile.html

API Location
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

Step by step api tutorial
http://hybridhacking.com/tutorials/building-facebook-applications-with-flex

Helpful Links
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi I want to develop facebook application for mobile using flex.please suggest some tutorials for this

Comment: Well this first tutoria will teach you how to develop a mobile application, in order to give your application facebook functionality you connect to the facebook api which I have also given you in links 2/3